# Error Message not Appearing from Stored Procedure which is executed as Part of Job in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need guidance on how to declare error message within stored procedure which will be fired through a job in SQL Server agent. I have declared RAISERROR which I read it will show up in the editor but it did not work for my case. Anyone knows how to rectify it?

Have tried using BEGIN TRY BEGIN CATCH, it did not work. My code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spDataDeletion
AS 
BEGIN
    -- Create a temporary table to store the latest records for each employee for subquery
    CREATE TABLE #LatestEmployeeRecords (
        LogID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
        HIST_EMP_IFXID varchar(10),
        HIST_AS_CURR_SESS NVARCHAR(100),
        RECORDS_DELETED INT,
        HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE DATE,
        DELETION_DATE DATE
    );

        -- Getting the current date
    DECLARE @DELETION_DATE DATETIME;
    SET @DELETION_DATE = GETDATE();


    -- Insert records into the #LatestEmployeeRecords table
    INSERT INTO #LatestEmployeeRecords (HIST_EMP_IFXID, HIST_AS_CURR_SESS, RECORDS_DELETED, HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE, DELETION_DATE)
    SELECT HIST_EMP_IFXID, HIST_AS_CURR_SESS, RECORDS_DELETED, HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE, @DELETION_DATE 
    FROM (
        SELECT HIST_EMP_IFXID, HIST_AS_CURR_SESS, COUNT(*) AS RECORDS_DELETED, HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE
        FROM [dbo].[tblHistory] 
        WHERE HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE < DATEADD(MONTH,-36, @DELETION_DATE)
        GROUP BY HIST_EMP_IFXID, HIST_AS_CURR_SESS, HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE
    ) t;

    -- ERROR HANDLING IF THERE IS NO RECORD TO BE DELETED -- 
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #LatestEmployeeRecords) = 0
        RAISERROR('All records are up to date.',11, 1);

    -- ERROR HANDLING IF HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE IS NULL --
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #LatestEmployeeRecords WHERE HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @NullEmployeeIds NVARCHAR(MAX);

        SELECT @NullEmployeeIds = COALESCE(@NullEmployeeIds + ', ', '') + CAST(HIST_EMP_IFXID AS NVARCHAR(10))
        FROM #LatestEmployeeRecords
        WHERE HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE IS NULL;

        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(1000) = 'Error: HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE is NULL for employee IDs: ' + @NullEmployeeIds;

        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 11, 1);
    END
    
    select * from #LatestEmployeeRecords;

    -- Delete old employee records from the tblHistory table
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[tblHistory]
    WHERE HIST_EMP_IFXID IN (
    SELECT HIST_EMP_IFXID FROM #LatestEmployeeRecords 
    WHERE HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE < DATEADD(MONTH,-36, @DELETION_DATE));

    -- Insert the latest employee records into the EmployeeLog table
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblLog_Data_Deletion] (LogID, HIST_EMP_IFXID, HIST_AS_CURR_SESS, RECORDS_DELETED, HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE, DELETION_DATE)
    SELECT LogID, HIST_EMP_IFXID, HIST_AS_CURR_SESS, RECORDS_DELETED, HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE, DELETION_DATE
    FROM #LatestEmployeeRecords;

    -- Drop the temporary table
    DROP TABLE #LatestEmployeeRecords;


END;
```

Comment: If you are running the SP though an agent job, then were are you expecting to see the error?

Comment: yeah correct, I am thinking of sending an email to the admin to notify the error other than showing the error message in the message box. Also, do you think creating an error log table is necessary? I feel it is useless as it does not affect business majorly. Happy to discuss.

Comment: It's a SQL Agent job... what message box? SQL Agent jobs are scheduled jobs that are running in a headless environment in the background and not on a user's desktop. Any printed output they issue will, if you're lucky, get recorded in the SQL Agent job step's log and/or the log file on disk if you have one configured. If you need to notify somebody when issues occur you probably need to use [alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/alerts) or CLR procedures to fire off messages via AWS-SNS/AWS-SQS/etc., or heaven forbid, emails. Not a big fan of email notifications, reasons...

Comment: I see, I was referring to the error message in the editor itself, apologize for not being clear. ok will look into alerts thank you for your suggestion! @AlwaysLearning

Comment: There's build in error notification mechanisms in sql server agent, one could even send a note to a pager. You could also build a separate notification framework. 
But looking at your code, i'm not sure the error can ever occur since you're checking for HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE  being NULL, but above you have WHERE HIST_AS_DATE_UPDATE < DATEADD(MONTH,-36, @DELETION_DATE); this would exclude the NULLs already.

Comment: If you want to capture errors and have them logged as part of the job execution with control over if the job step(s) have warnings or throw errors you can use `msdb.dbo.sp_sqlagent_log_jobhistory` - specifically controlling the *@Message* and *@RunStatus* properties